# Finding partial derivatives given a surface equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the surface $\displaystyle F(x,y,z)=x^7z^8+\sin(y^2z^8)+6=0$.

I need to find $∂z/∂x$ & $∂z/∂y$

1) I found $∂F/∂x$, $∂F/∂y$, and $∂F/∂z$
2) I then took $-(∂F/∂z)/(∂F/∂x)$ to find $∂z/∂x$, but the answer was outputting as incorrect.

Is this the correct way to do it? Because if so, then it's telling me I am finding the partials incorrectly, but I used my calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was dividing incorrectly. Instead of -(∂F/∂z)/(∂F/∂x) it should be -(∂F/∂x)/(∂F/∂z)